# the user account changed to standard and i can't adminstrate the computer please help

Tags: macbook-pro

I was trying to change the settings like profile name and other settings when I clicked on the lock symbol to open this setting to change it. I accidentally clicked on and doesn't allow my user account to administrate the computer and restart the computer, unfortunately. this is what I did. – the user account changed to standard and when I tried to change the setting again, the computer asked me to enter my username and password, and I entered them but it didn't work although they were correct.

Comment: Reposting the same question again won’t help. Please edit the original one with additional details and things you’ve tried so far.